# calling EntityTypeBuilder<T>.HasKey via reflection for compound keys

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, reflection, entity-framework-core

I'm attempting to add "History" tables to EFCore, and have it mostly working.  For every POCO in my model that has a [Historyable] attribute on the class, I use reflection to generate a new class that has three additional properties in addition to the properties that are in the original class - ChangeDate, ChangeType, and ChangeUserID.

My problem comes when I need to set the primary key for the new generated History type.  In hand written code, adding the primary keys would look something like:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<EquipmentPortProfile>().HasKey(k => new { k.Name, k.PortType, k.CardType })
modelBuilder.Entity<EquipmentPortProfileHistory>().HasKey(k => new { k.Name, k.PortType, k.CardType, k.ChangeDate })  // add ChangeDate to keep it unique
```

where EquipmentPortProfile is the original [Historable] POCO that I can manually call HasKey() for and EquipmentPortProfileHistory is the new generated type that I need to call HasKey() for via reflection.

I've got the following code which adds the new History type of the model, but I can't quite figure out how to generically invoke the call to HasKey() with the List of MemberExpressions I've built.

```
var type = tbuilder.CreateType();  // create the new History type
var entityMethod = typeof(ModelBuilder).GetMethods().First(f => f.Name == "Entity");
var ent = entityMethod.MakeGenericMethod(type).Invoke(modelBuilder, new object[] { });  // add the new History type to the model
var haskey = ent.GetType().GetMethods().FirstOrDefault(m => m.Name == "HasKey");
var param = Expression.Parameter(type, "k");  List<MemberExpression> args = new List<MemberExpression>();
var pk = historable.FindPrimaryKey();
foreach (var prop in pk.Properties)  // we add in the same key properties as the table that we are tracking
    args.Add(Expression.PropertyOrField(param, prop.Name));

args.Add(Expression.PropertyOrField(param, "ChangeDate"));  // and then also add in ChangeDate as part of the PK to keep it unique
```

Comment: You can get hash like this : (k.Name + "^" +  k.PortType + "^" +  k.CardType + "^" + k.ChangeDate).GetHashCode()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest is to use the [HasKey](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.metadata.builders.entitytypebuilder.haskey?view=efcore-2.1) overload accepting `params string[] propertyNames` argument.

Also there is no need to call the generic `Entity<TEntity>` method via reflection, you can simply use the non generic [Entity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.modelbuilder.entity?view=efcore-2.1#Microsoft_EntityFrameworkCore_ModelBuilder_Entity_System_Type_) method accepting `Type type` argument, e.g. something like this

```
var type = tbuilder.CreateType();  // create the new History type
var pk = historable.FindPrimaryKey();

var pkPropertyNames = pk.Properties.Select(p => p.Name).Append("ChangeDate").ToArray();
modelBuilder.Entity(type).HasKey(pkPropertyNames);
```

Comment: DOH!  I guess I should have looked more carefully at the overloads to see that reflection wasn't even needed.  I verified your easy peasy method works.  Many thanks!